# Spectrum of compact operator on an infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space (over $\mathbb{C}$) and let $T\colon X\to X$ be a compact operator. Let $\sigma(T)$ denote the spectrum of $T$ and let $\sigma_{\text{p}}(T)$ denote the point spectrum (= eigenvalues) of $T$. Is it true that $$\sigma(T)=\sigma_{\text{p}}(T)\cup\{0\}?$$ I have seen some theorems, but none of them explicitly says that the above equality is true.

Comment: Rudin, *Functional Analysis*, Theorem 4.25 explicitly says that.